# How to focus 'Ok' Button when JQuery alert dialog is triggered from server side code C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want that when `JQuery alert dialog` is triggered from server side code (`C#`) then it "`OK`" button should be auto focused so that when i press enter key dialog should disappear.

My following JQuery alert box `"OK"`button is focused when client side code trigger it but does not focused when triggered from C# server side code:

**JQuery**

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
        function MessageBox(message) {
            $(function () {
                $("#modal_dialog").html(message);
                $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
                    title: "Info",
                    resizable: false,
                    height: "auto",
                    width: 400,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                           
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    open: function () {
                        $(this).parent().find('button:nth-child(1)').focus();
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        }
    </script>
```

**Server Side C#**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "p2", "<script>MessageBox('Password Matched');</script>", true);
```

Comment: Your MessageBox code contains a reference to a variable named `focusElement `. Where is that declared and how is it populated?

Comment: I have remove these lines but still same behaviour